# Heroku: installing Postgres without local db | Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I've already pushed my Django files to Heroku via Git and now I'd like to configure at Heroku server the Postgres database. After that, I need to transfer my local sqlite database to Heroku Postgres.

All of this issue is because I don't have admin rights on my local PC (corporate unit) to install Postgres.

So basically:

```
1. Configure remotely Postegres at Heroku;
2. Migrate local database (sqlite) to Heroku (Postgres).
```

I don't know if there is another path to go on...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's some crazy gymnastics you're trying to do. Getting a grasp of PostgreSQL setup is hard as it is. There are several user/table privileges you have to maintain. Sqlite3 has very simple settings in the `settings.py` file in Django, while Postgres requires a username, password, Host, and Port.

Also the sql you export from sqlite3, might not ingest directly into the PostgreSQL. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30544492/revisions). You'll have to install Postgres on your local machine, if you plan to have any sort of ok workflow as far as I can see. You can probably explore docker to create a local dev environment on your corporate PC.

Comment: Fortunatelly, I got installed a previous PostegreSQL (10.X) via binary code. Thank you for your reply.